# What "whizzy new tools" in space are America and its allies using to track China’s military activity and illegal fishing? (The Economist)

Tags: united-states, china, military, maritime-law, fishing

#### Background and evidence of research effort

The non-paywalled part of the Economist's August 15, 2023 [Keeping tabs on China’s murky maritime manoeuvres; America and its allies are using whizzy new tools to track China’s military activity and illegal fishing](https://www.economist.com/china/2023/08/15/keeping-tabs-on-chinas-murky-maritime-manoeuvres) begins:

> In January 2021 a fleet of Chinese fishing vessels approached the coast of Oman, apparently searching for squid. **According to the ships’ automatic identification transponders, they stayed just outside Oman’s Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ), which grants it control of fishing rights up to 200 nautical miles (370km) from its shores. But radio signals from the ships, detected by commercial satellites, told a different story.** They indicated that the ships were operating within Oman’s EEZ in a suspected illegal raid on its valuable squid stocks.
>
> **That was an early demonstration of a new tool being used by America and its allies to help expose illegal or aggressive Chinese activity at sea. They are contracting private companies to provide governments across the Indo-Pacific region with near-real-time data, gathered from space,** to help them monitor coastal waters and to use their limited naval and coastguard resources more effectively.

Maritime [Automatic identification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) is an (apparently optional) self-identification and self-reporting system. A device on a ship receives [GNSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation#Global_navigation_satellite_systems) signals (e.g., GPS) signals, calculates speed and direction, adds a user-entered (or at least user-hackable) identification code, and sends the information out as a radio signal that can be picked up by other ships and by satellites. There are maritime websites (analogous to [FR24](https://www.flightradar24.com/52.52,13.39/4) but for ships) that aggregate and display the information, but it's still a presentation of self-reported, good-faith data.

It is widely reported that fishing vessels as well as clandestine military supply ships just turn the damn thing off when they don't want to be tracked.

Since alas, I no longer have a subscription to The Economist, I'd like to ask:

#### Question:

What "whizzy new tools" in space are America and its allies are using to track China’s military activity and illegal fishing?

Satellite imagery from low Earth orbit (LEO) is spotty because it requires a recent pass of a satellite - [Planet Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Labs#Flock_satellite_constellations) has a constellation of ~10 cm aperture cameras in cubesats and smallsats but these are insufficient to identify specific ships and not ideal to spot a ship at sea if you don't already have a good idea where to look.

Using [Synthetic Aperture Radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic-aperture_radar) ships at sea stand out like bright stars in a dark night sky, (cf. [Star-shaped artifacts in SAR images of the "Suez Canal traffic jam seen from space"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51087/12102)) (and works through cloud cover, day and night) but the satellites are (currently) few and far between so again, coverage is spotty.

So I'm really interested to find out what these "whizzy new tools" are that are based on data from private companies that provide "near-real-time data, gathered from space."

Comment: first Politics SE question to be tagged with [military + fishing](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing+military)

Comment: It sounds like a propaganda article frankly, in how it wrangles the facts into an American vs Chinese narrative. Lawlessness amongst fishermen is common everywhere, because the fish move arbitrarily, and governance of fishing activity on the high sea is balkanised between different nations.

Comment: Looking into it the web seems to be full of pages quoting the Economist article without explaining what "whizzy new tools" are supposed to be. Some mention "new" space-based remote sensing, or merchant ship-based imaging systems tied into military networks. To me it seems like the kind of lazy, stenographic "reporting" when press releases are just reprinted verbatim.

Comment: @Steve have you *read the article yet?* There's been plenty of technological efforts to better track fishing vessels that have their AIS turned off or otherwise compromised, it's a real and substantial effort. The Economist doesn't publish fluff. I assume it's going to be some combination of visible and IR imaging, SAR, passive radar and communications interception (e.g. ship-to-ship coms and satphones) picked up by other satellites among other things.

Comment: @shashin-ka ditto

Comment: Voting to close - This is a really interesting question but sadly I have to agree with the others that it is more a a question about technology and not in scope with "governments, policies and political processes". I think this is best asked in [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @uhoh, it's interesting technologically, but I don't understand why it's specifically said to combat illegal Chinese fishing activity. Unless the Chinese have a particularly poor reputation perhaps, but in Europe it's more common to hear of the British and French setting their boats to ramming speed, than the Chinese.

Comment: Is this really so difficult to do with satellite images? Ships are big so even with low resolution you can see them. They are probably hard to identify but they move slowly so you can just keep track of them if you have a picture every couple of minutes or maybe even hours. My guess would be that some private companies do exactly that.

Comment: @quarague Yes it is so difficult. Satellites don't hover - those in low orbit (where you can image ships at all) are moving 7,800 meters/sec. They can't sit there and take a picture every couple of hours. The ocean an area of 3,610,000,00,00,000 square meters. And you'll need the best spy satellites (optical or SAR) in order to even make a rough guess on the identify of a ship. Without knowing where to look, even doing "hey! there are some dots!" is a huge challenge. ID and behavior is even far harder.

Comment: @Steve what does ramming speed have to do with anything? Per the block quote "They indicated that the ships were operating within Oman’s EEZ in a suspected illegal raid on its valuable squid stocks." Are large numbers of British and French turing off their AIS in coordinated fashion and entering each other's EEZs? It seems that many of these comments were left after only skimming the title. [Have you read the article yet?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80926/what-whizzy-new-tools-in-space-are-america-and-its-allies-using-to-track-china?noredirect=1#comment350853_80926)

Comment: @uhoh, yes the problem of conflict over fishing territories - of fishing fleets "raiding" areas that supposedly belong to another - is a familiar one in the UK. Boat owners have tended to be petite bourgeois types who are difficult to control and discipline, and who have strong incentives to catch fish under any terms (because they're small and poorly organised, so it's difficult to accept good days with bad, or charge the market enough price that you can comfortably come back from sea empty-handed), so it's been a perennial problem, from the "cod wars" of the 70s to the Brexit era recently.

Comment: @uhoh, I'm not following the logic of your last remarks, to be honest. I don't have any "concerns about topicality". Did you intend to tag me?

Comment: @sfxedit There are two SE sites that we don't have yet but I think would thrive - Optics & Photonics (those questions get spotty answers at best in Physics SE) and War & Military Technology SE. I understand you concern about topicality, but the proposed "better" Engineering SE is not likely to generate answers about how governments are using contracted technology to address international trade issue ("stealing fish") and non-standard/gray zone military tactics (this site does; sometimes). Can you point to some at-least-similar questions that got answers in Engineering as proof of principle?

Comment: @Steve oh, indeed it was mis (at)ed, thanks.

Comment: @uhoh The issue I see with allowing these kinds of question is how do we know that the answers are correct? SEs are topical so that subject "experts" can review the answers. And 2nd, if this is allowed how do we discourage the inevitable questions like *"Can the US F-16s really beat the Russian SU-27 in Ukraine?*.

Comment: @sfxedit the same way we do with any answer; as [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80949/16047) does, via some combination of logic and supporting sources. The question would of course be "How do the capabilities of F-16 and SU-27 compare in a direct confrontation in overland warfare?" or something like that. All new sites need a little time to decide what kinds of questions work and which ones don't. It's not necessarily easy.

Comment: @sfxedit Since there is so much information available on modern (and older) military equipment and its capabilities, and who's buying what, as well as the outcomes of military conflicts, I think there's certainly a large, rich fact base out there from which a Warfare & Military Technology SE site could draw questions and answers. Right now Politics, History, and a tiny corner of Space SE is where war can get a foothold in Stack Exchange, and since has such a huge footprint and impact on the real world, it could easily keep its own site active.

Comment: @sfxedit checking myself: [What are the current sites that questions about warfare & military technology are on-topic and asked & answered with some regularity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392498/303080)

Comment: @uhoh The example of the answer to this question that you cited to support your arguments, also supports my view - since I am not an "expert" on this subject, I really can't judge whether the technical claims are factual and accurate. But as someone who understands politics better I can formulate many political theories on the answer (like - is this promoting the technology / the company or is it trying to exaggerate the claims of the technology so that nobody questions what the US or other users of this tech claim? etc.). Also see this https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5956/45056

Comment: @uhoh Also, since you are a very active member on many SEs and do have a flair for community building, have you considered starting an SEs on these topics yourself? Please check out [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). I am sure you could attract many members from History and Po.SE to a new Military SE.

Comment: @sfxedit sure, I've thought about it a lot; but actually I feel as though I have just the opposite of community building skills. I would love to be involved and put substantial effort into one or both of those potential Area 51 candidates, but in all these years I've only managed to figure out how to write question posts - and more recently answer posts. So I'm not the right "point person" to get that started. But if either were to start I'd be there right away to contribute to the effort.

Comment: @uhoh In any online community, quality content creation (and moderation) is the most difficult part. You are decent at that. Then it's all about promoting and increasing user participation. There are already 100's of question on this subject among varied subs. Collating that into the new sub, and inviting the users who contributed to these Q&A can help with the initial user participation part to kickstartthe process. The only hurdle is the time and commitment it will take in the beginning.

Comment: @sfxedit you make good points... I will give it some serious thought. I don't know what "Collating that into the new sub..." actually means in practice though.

Comment: @uhoh *I don't know what "Collating that into the new sub..." actually means in practice* - I remember reading somewhere that you can ask the mods of SEs to move the questions to your new SE (based on the tags indicating the topicality). So if History.SE has questions with tags like military-strategy (for example), you can request them to move those questions to your new SE. You will have to research and evaluate those questions from your end to make their job easier. (Though I am not sure when this process is supposed to happened - when you propose the community in Area51 or afterwards).

Answer (score 3):

The *new and improved* technology is "radio frequency data acquisition, an application of military signals intelligence for the maritime world." <sup>[[1](https://maritime-executive.com/article/satellite-rf-tracking-follows-the-dark-ships-that-ais-can-t-see)]</sup> Even with their AIS turned off or "spoofed" there are other radio frequencies emitted from the ships that act as a signature for tracking.

Three companies: Unseen Labs, Kleos Space, and Spire Global, use the technology.

> Using satellite receivers, companies like Unseen Labs, Kleos Space and Spire Global monitor a wide swath of the RF spectrum for all kinds of radio emissions. Their satellites can geolocate the source of a radio frequency transmission from a ship - for example, its radio communications.
>
> **According to Unseen Labs, the "fingerprint" of each ship's unique RF signature is much harder to spoof or turn off than the AIS transciever on the bridge. When the crew of a suspect vessel shuts off their AIS, their "dark" vessel is still emitting on other frequencies, so it is just as visible to RF tracking satellites as it was before.** The concept works in all conditions, day or night, fair weather or foul. Combined with synthetic aperture radar or visual imaging for confirmation, it can be a useful tool for tracking ships that do not want to be tracked.

The U.S. Navy has partnered with Kleos Space. <sup>[[2](https://maritime-executive.com/article/u-s-navy-uses-satellite-tracking-to-find-ships-by-rf-emissions)]</sup> Kleos uses many orbiting clusters, each with four satellites, for accurate triangulation of each ship's position.

Comment: *Excellent!* Thanks for your perseverance on this and getting it answered before the "answer-prevention team"'s work is complete. :-) I added a block quote to avoid link-onliness and keep the informative part here in SE.